# Is it possible to bind CommitEditCommand on a Datagrid to an ICommand in the view model?

Tags: .net, wpf, viewmodel, wpfdatagrid, icommand

I'm trying to do something similar to;

```
<Button Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" />
```

Where DeleteCommand is an ICommand exposed by the view model.

I thought i could do something similar to the following, but this doesn't seem to be the case;

```
<DataGrid CommitEditCommand="{Binding CommitCommand}" />
```

Basically i'm trying to capture the event occurence in the view model and act on it.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial hunch is no...this is based off the readings from Vincent Sibal's [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2008/10/01/overview-of-the-editing-features-in-the-wpf-datagrid.aspx).

It appears that the `CommitEditCommand` on the `DataGrid` calls the [IEditableCollectionView](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2008/05/20/wpf-3-5-sp1-feature-ieditablecollectionview.aspx) counterpart. So...

`DataGrid.CommitEditCommand` -> `IEditableCollectionView.CommitEdit` -> `IEditableObject.EndEdit`

Therefore if your model is implementing `IEditableObject` and you were on a cell within the `DataGrid` hitting Enter (InputBinding stored via the CommandManager) will by default execute the `DataGrid.CommitEditCommand` and set off the cascade of actions down stream as mentione dabove..

The blog does speak about making use of events such as `RowEditEnding` or `CellEditEnding` to cancel the command which would mean in theory you could cancel the command and at that point route to your desired behavior.